# Is there a way to capture the file path and name in the same batch function?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am creating a batch script to perform `robocopy` functions.  Currently I am having to call two different PowerShell selections, one for the file name and then one for the source folder, can I combine this?

Using the code below I can capture the file name, but can I capture both using one method?

```
echo Select your file
set pwshcmd=powershell -NoProfile -Command "&{[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms') | Out-Null;$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog; $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()|Out-Null; $OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName}"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%pwshcmd%') do (
    set "FileName=%%I"
)

echo %FileName%

pause
```

I wish for the user to make one selection with PowerShell and it set two variables `%FileName%` and `%FilePath%`, as this will be used in the `robocopy` script.

Comment: Get your PowerShell script to return a full qualified filename (like `C:\path to\my file\filename.ext`) Then in your `for`loop `set "filename=%%~nx"` and `set "filepath=%%~dpI"`

Comment: As `robocopy.exe` is an executable file in its own right, I'd recommend that you simply do it all in `PowerShell` because you can run [tag:robocopy].exe in exactly the same way in a [tag:powershell].exe window.

Comment: Why not write the whole thing in powershell? This appears to just open a file dialog box and list contents right? You can invoke Powershell in the windows console.

Comment: Right, could do this..  This is actually part of a multi-tool application that I'm building for our partners, it just allows easier access for robocopy but includes a custom file compare feature, xcopy and a few other tools, we just wanted to consolidate.
Regardless, this was solved with what Sephan mentioned (or somewhat), where I just added: `set "r_copy_file_source_path=%%~pI"` and `set "r_copy_file_source=%%~nxI"`

Comment: I'd include `$OpenFileDialog.MultiSelect=$False` and use `$OpenFileDialog.FileName` for the fully qualified file name you could then split with the tilde `~` modifiers.

Comment: LotPings, exactly!  I forgot to mention that obviously .SafeFileName wouldn't work for this, so I did use that .FileName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's input on this question.  I had solved it shortly after posting, however I did run into the fact that robocopy wants a directory path without the ending "\".  The method used to gather both paths were:

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%pwshcmd%') do (
set "r_copy_file_source_path=%%~dpI"
set "r_copy_file_source=%%~nxI"
)
```

This provided me with both variables required, then I trimmed the ending "\" from the path with:

```
set r_copy_file_source_path=%r_copy_file_source_path:~0,-1%
```

Again, I appreciate the responses!  Thank you!